# How use layer-list to create custom background

Tags: android, xml, styles

I'm trying to play the background image below using layer-list, but without much success
-> https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XBFL.png

I used this example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:right="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="20dp"
            android:height="3dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#f00"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="4dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:right="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="20dp"
            android:height="5dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="5dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:right="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="20dp"
            android:height="5dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#0f0"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape  android:shape="oval"
            xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
            <solid android:color="#F44336"
                android:angle="270"/>
            <size
                android:width="56dp"
                android:height="56dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_done_white_24dp"
       android:top="16dp" android:left="16dp" android:bottom="16dp" android:right="16dp">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I solved this:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    
        <item android:bottom="8dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    
        <item android:bottom="9dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@color/gray" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    
    
    </layer-list>